# Nested for loop over data returns TypeError: iterator method is not callable

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a data structure similar to the below; Simply I list of items, however, some items have nested items. I am calling the objects that have nested objects "sections" for the purposes of this question.

```
data = [
  {title: "Section 1", items: [{id: "1"}, {id: "2"}]},
  {title: "Section 2", items: [{id: "3"}, {id: "4"}]},
  {id: "5"},
  {id: "6"},
  {id: "7"},
]
```

I am trying to loop through the items within the "sections" and then the remaining items however, I am getting the above error.

### Attempt 1:

```
function addIsFavourite(favourites = [], sections) {
  for (const section of sections) {
    if ("items" in section) {
      // Section has nested items
      for (const item of section.items) {
        item.isFavourite = favourites.includes(item.id);
      }
    } else {
      // Section holds items directly
      for (const item of section) {
        item.isFavourite = favourites.includes(item.id);
      }
    }
  }
  return sections;
}
```

Returns error

> [TypeError: iterator method is not callable]

### Attempt 2:

```
function addIsFavourite(favourites = [], sections) {
  if ("items" in sections) {
    for (const section of sections) {
      for (const item of section.items) {
        item.isFavourite = favourites.includes(item.id);
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (const item of sections) {
      item.isFavourite = favourites.includes(item.id);
    }
  }
  return sections;
}
```

This only works on the first "section".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering indicates that you're trying to iterate over an object that doesn't have a callable iterator method. In your code, it seems like you're assuming that section can be both an object and an array, but you need to handle these cases differently.

Here's a revised version of your code that checks if section is an array before attempting to iterate over its items:

```js
const data = [
      { title: "Section 1", items: [{ id: "1" }, { id: "2" }] },
      { title: "Section 2", items: [{ id: "3" }, { id: "4" }] },
      { id: "5" },
      { id: "6" },
      { id: "7" },
    ];
    
    const favourites = ["1", "4", "6"];
    
    function addIsFavourite(favourites = [], sections) {
      for (let section of sections) {
        if ("items" in section) {
          // Section has nested items
          for (let item of section.items) {
            item.isFavourite = favourites.includes(item.id);
          }
        } else if (Array.isArray(section)) {
          // Section holds items directly
          for (let item of section) {
            item.isFavourite = favourites.includes(item.id);
          }
        } else {
          // Section is a standalone item
          section.isFavourite = favourites.includes(section.id);
        }
      }
      return sections;
    }
    
    const result = addIsFavourite(favourites, data);
    
    console.log(result);
```

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to loop through each `section` object, which only contains an `id` property and doesn't have the iterator protocol. You don't need a loop there as you're already in the scope of each section.

Neither do you need the `else` block as you'd probably want to check if the section itself is in the `favourites` array at any time.

```
function addIsFavourite(favourites = [], sections) {
  for (const section of sections) {
    if ("items" in section) {
      // Section has nested items
      for (const item of section.items) {
        item.isFavourite = favourites.includes(item.id);
      }
    }

    section.isFavourite = favourites.includes(section.id);
  }

  return sections;
}
```

If you want loop through an object and use the iterator protocol, then you'd need to use the [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) static method to convert an object to an array, which can be iterated over with `for...of`.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change the `else` block to only include the line `section.isFavourite = favourites.includes(section.id)`.

You can also solve the problem with a one-liner like this:

```js
const data = [
  {title: "Section 1", items: [{id: "1"}, {id: "2"}]},
  {title: "Section 2", items: [{id: "3"}, {id: "4"}]},
  {id: "5"},
  {id: "6"},
  {id: "7"},
]

let favourites = ["1", "6"]

data.flatMap(x => x.items ?? x)
  .forEach(item => favourites.includes(item.id) && (item.isFavourite = true))

console.log(data)
```

`data.flatMap(x => x.items ?? x)` will produce an array of all items at the first and second level (it will break if you have three levels of nesting, and you'd have to use recursion or a stack instead).

Then, you can simply use `forEach` to set `item.isFavourite` where necessary.